# Accidently Removed mysql-server from kali linux 2017.1. How To Reinstall It?

Tags: linux, mysql, kali-linux, reinstall, package-management

I have accidentally removed `mysql-server` from my Kali Linux 2017.1 by using following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get auto remove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

When I tried to reinstall it using command `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, it shows an error as follows

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
```

Please tell me how to reinstall `mysql-server` completely?

Answer (score 1):

Kali Linux uses most commonly used MariaDB rather than MySQL in it's installations. You can install the MariaDB for by ,

```
apt install mariadb-server
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql-server` is a metapackage. The real package is likely `mysql-server-5.7` (same for mysql-client).